# How to delete selected Items from a ListView by pressing the delete button?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I want to delete one or more selected Items from a ListView.
What is the best way to do that?
I´m using C# and the dotnet Framework 4.

Comment: See this post on stackoverflow.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330624/asp-net-listview-how-to-delete-a-row-without-deleting-from-datasource

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can delete all selected items by iterating the [ListView.SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection and calling [ListView.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for each item whenever the user pressed the delete key.

```
private void listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keys.Delete == e.KeyCode)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem listViewItem in ((ListView)sender).SelectedItems)
        {
            listViewItem.Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that throw an exception beause the collection you're iterating on is changed within the loop?

Comment: Unfortunately my KeyPress event handler is called only for keys like 'a', 'b', 'c', '.' and so on, not for control keys.

Comment: I found these code doesn't work fine, and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs_members(v=vs.90).aspx according to this page, there isn't a KeyCode property in KeyPressEventArgs, anyone can help me?

Comment: Use KeyDown event instead.

Comment: what about listView.SelectedItems.Clear();

Comment: @BartoszWójcik ListView.SelectedItems.Clear() just clears the selection, not the underlying ListView.Items

Answer (score 6):

I think there is something called listView.Items.Remove(listView.SelectedItem) and you can call it from your delete button's click event. Or run a foreach loop and see if the item is selected, remove it.

```
foreach(var v in listView.SelectedItems)
{
   listView.Items.Remove(v)
}
```

Comment: perhaps - `listView.Items.Remove((ListViewItem) v);` :)

Comment: Or even `foreach (ListViewItem v in listView.SelectedItems)` :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the easiest mode.

```
private void listView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
  {
    this.listView.Items.Remove(listView.SelectedItem);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// Get an array of all selected items
ListViewItem[] selectedItems = (from i in listView.Items where i.Selected select i).ToArray();

// Delete the items
foreach (ListViewItem item in selectedItems)
    listView.Items.Remove(item);
```

<strike>**EDIT**

I just noticed that the `ListView` class already has a `SelectedItems` property. To make sure that you're not changing the collection you're iterating on, I'd copy that collection first:</strike>

Seems the above (using `AddRange`) did not work. I thought that removing the items by iterating over the `SelectedItems` enumerable would cause an exception, but obviously it does not. So my original code code be modified to match the other answers... sorry for posting non-functional code...

Comment: You can´t convert the SelectedItems to a List<ListViewItem>selectedItems.AddRange(listView.SelectedItems); I casted it with (IEnumerable<ListViewItem>).  Ok that seems to work. But how do a catch the "Press Del Event"?

Comment: No sorry the cast dont works. Stil get this error "ListViewItemCollection is not assinable  to parametertype IEnumeralbe

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit unrelated but In WPF the mentioned methods did not work for me. I had to create a copy of the selected items and use these to remove items in the listview.:

```
private void ListBox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Delete)
            {

                var lst = new List<object>();

                foreach (var itemSelected in ListBox.SelectedItems)
                {
                    lst.Add(itemSelected);
                }

                foreach (var lstitem in lst)
                {
                    ListBox.Items.Remove(lstitem);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Question was about WinForms, maybe that's why.