# Add subitems in listview selected item

Tags: c#, listview, subitem

I have a listview which has 5 columns and it is editable i used the hitinfo,  when i double click the column 4 i the datepicker will appear in column 4 and display the value of it, Now i when i press the backspace i want to remove the value of the selected item in column4.

here is my code.

```
private void dtpicker_Keydown(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    if (e.keycode == keys.back)
       {
         lv1.selecteditems[0].subitems.add("");
       }
}
```

but when i run the application it didnt remove

here is my listview data.

```
Column1    Column2    Column3    Column4    Column5
 1           3         4         5/5/2015      2
 3           5         3         5/5/2015      3
```

I want this kind of Result

```
Column1    Column2    Column3    Column4    Column5
   1           3         4                       2
   3           5         3         5/5/2015      3
```

Comment: Try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829678/how-to-delete-selected-items-from-a-listview-by-pressing-the-delete-button
Add a handling for Backspace instead of Delete.

Comment: i get it but i want only the text in specific column not all selected item

Comment: Why are you adding `SubItem` when you need to make it empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the indexing, the `KeyDown` event including the `SuppressKeyPress` , and the way to access the `SubItem.Text`:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
    {
        lv1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text = "";
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

We need to cancel the event, so we don't throw an exception for deleting any of the Date fields.

Note that I left out any checking, e.g. for `SelectedItems.Count > 0` or for the count of the relevant `SubItems` collection..