# Delete row from a programmatically created table

Tags: asp.net

In an asp.net listview I'm putting a table

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr> 
    <td style="width:90%"><asp:TextBox Enabled="false" ID="txtOverall" Text='<%#Eval("Overall") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td style="width:10%"><asp:Button ID="cmdDelete" OnClick="DeleteRow" ToolTip='<%#Eval("tooltip") %>' class="alert tiny button" Text="x" runat="server"  /></td>
   </tr> 
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Which basically is a text string and next to it I want a button that will delete the row that the button appears on.  The table holds more fields than this but for simplicity this the basic structure. All of the data is entered programmatically. Does anyone know how I can remove a single row from the table?

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: Do you want to delete one of the items in the `ListView`(the one where the user clicked at `cmdDelete`)? What was the problem? Handle the `ItemCommand` and delete it from the datasource, then bind it again.

Comment: may be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330624/asp-net-listview-how-to-delete-a-row-without-deleting-from-datasource

Answer (score 0):

**You need to handle the delete command**

```
  private void OnRecordDeleting(Object source, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e) {    
       //your deleting code
     }
```

**and asp**

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource
        id="SqlDataSource1"
        runat="server"
        DataSourceMode="DataSet"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Orders"            
        OnDeleting="OnRecordDeleting"
        OnDeleted="OnRecordDeleted">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: The table isn't bound to a datasource, the data that's being collected is just being held temporarily (it's a long story)

Comment: @SxChoc: Where do you hold it? Just use a List or DataTable as datasource, then remove it in `ItemCommand` and `DataBind` it again afterwards.

Comment: It's held in the pages viewstate. What I can't 'see' is what uniquely identifys a row or how to delete one of them